# Is there a lodash function to merge two objects and delete properties of one of them if they don't exist in the other?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Consider the following two objects:

```
const source = {
  foo: 'value',
  bar: 'value',
  baz: 'value'
};

const pattern = {
  foo: '',
  bar: ''
};

_.fn(source, pattern); // { foo: 'value', bar: 'value' }
```

In this example 'baz' property is deleted because it doesn't exist in the pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

_.pick can help

```
_.pick(source,Object.keys(pattern))
```

Comment: `pick` creates a new object with these properties. What if you want to delete the missing properties from the original object?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mutate the original `source` object for inline key deletion instead of returning a new one, you can do:

```
_.difference(_.keys(source), _.keys(pattern)).forEach(k => delete source[k])
```

Or just plain JS:

```
Object.keys(source)
  .filter(k => Object.keys(pattern).includes(k))
  .forEach(k => delete source[k])
```

I generally design for immutability, but this approach might be useful if you want to avoid the overhead of allocating a new object, or you have a lot of primitives that would need copying over by value to a fresh object.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do as well, is look for intersection ofthose two objects:

```
var a = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };
var b = { 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5 };

_.intersection(_.keys(a), _.keys(b)); // ['c']
```